# disabling the button. when cells in the schedule are unchecked

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How to disable the save button when all checkboxes are unchecked, and if at least one hour selected in the schedule will be, the save button becomes active?
Please help.
My code:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-slrmqc?fbclid=IwAR3mZbHjz8TkLUZJI1kd7gsMnaPikdS0eyGzdF17RPYJ70jyHhXMOzW8x3w&file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `checkIsAllUnchecked` method

```
  checkIsAllUnchecked() {
    this.isAllUnchecked = this.arr.every((row) =>
      row.items.every((col) => col === 0)
    );
  }
```

and call it in `ngOnInit`, `click` and `toggleRow` methods

and add the check to the Save button

```
<button [disabled]="isAllUnchecked" (click)="save()">Save</button>
```